# How do I interpret this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have been reading an article on how to speed up laptops or PCs and I came across a sentence which I am unsure about how to interpret it.

Whole text:

> Unfortunately, as computers get older they invariably get slower. If
>   your laptop or PC feels like it's crawling along, we've got a series
>   of handy hints and tips on how to bring it back up to speed.

The confusing sentence :

> If your laptop or PC feels like it's crawling along, we've got a
>   series of handy hints and tips on how to **bring it back up to speed**.

First I tried to parse the sentence. I know bring something back means to return something. I also to know " up to " means to a certain extent. Now I don't know whether should I interpret the sentence like:

They have got a series of handy hints and tips that would bring the speed of a slow laptop or PC completely back, just like their first day.

or

They have got a series of handy hints and tips that would just bring the speed of slow laptop or PC back only to a certain extent, not completely.

Comment: Just a side note, remember the pronoun `I` is always capitalised.

Answer (score 1):

> how to bring it back up to speed

This is a mildly punning use of a common phrase which is itself a figurative use.

When you enter a major highway from a side street you are usually moving much slower than the traffic already on the highway. If just steer into the traffic flow you are likely to be rear-ended. Consequently, there's typically an acceleration lane where you can bring your car "up to speed"—that is, up to the speed of the highway traffic, so you can merge safely.

[image]

This image is often used to speak about introducing a new person to a project: we "get them up to speed", inform them about what's being done and who's doing what, so they can "merge" into the project and make a contribution rather than bringing everything to a crashing halt.

The author of your article uses the same phrase to speak not of bringing your computer to some implicitly limited speed but of *returning* it to its full original speed: the point at which it is operating most efficiently.